# How to estimate a dynamic Tobit model

Tags: random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, lags, tobit-regression, dynamic-regression

I have data which correspond to a corner solution. The Tobit-model seems to be adequate for this data. However, I also wants to control for a baseline variable (t-1) and unobserved heterogenity. This is normally not permissable in the Tobit model.

I understand that Wooldridge have solved the problem in this paper: http://download.clib.psu.ac.th/datawebclib/e_resource/trial_database/WileyInterScienceCD/pdf/JAE/JAE_4.pdf (page 49-50)

My problem is that I am weak in mathematics. Thus, I don't understand what Wooldridge proposes in the paper just mentioned.

Can somebody please explain to me (in plain language), step by step, the process which I should follow in order to build a dynamic Tobit model.